# Showing data only for one row in a grouped view

Tags: list

I want to show data only for first row in a grouped view, is that any way possible with out of box solution or by jQuery? Below is my view

[image]

What I would like to do is when child items are listed in a group and if it has multiple rows than only first row will display data for all columns except the column "FIS Sub Account".

Sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible OOB, but you can try with this bit of jQuery:

```
$('tbody[groupstring]').next().children(':first').siblings().hide();
```

I'm assuming that your view Group By setting is set to expandend by default, otherwise you'll have to fiddle a little bit with the click event on the collapse/expand +/- handle.

Comment: Where do you put this line?